# Creating a temporal soap film GAM with mgcv

Tags: generalized-additive-model, smoothing, mgcv

I've been experimenting with using soap film smoothers in `mgcv` to estimate the densities of a species over space given aerial imagery of the species' extent and in situ observations of densities. I have both types of data from multiple years, and would like to build a model that incorporates changes in *both* the density of the species and changes to the species' spatial extent.

To illustrate what I mean, here's the model fitted using thin plate regression splines:

```
m1 <- gam(density ~ s(x, y, by = year), data = syn_dat_tprs, method = "REML",
          family = tw(link = "log"))
```

The predicted output from fitting the model using two years of data is then:

[image]

That's all well and good, but now I'd like to fit the model using a soap film smoother. However, the challenge is that multiple boundaries defined within a smooth term cannot overlap. Hence, boundaries of the same population across years cannot be used unless the boundaries are radically different (these are plants, so they're not). Here's where it gets hack-y.

The soap film smoother, by definition, only smooths over the domain within the boundary, so my thinking is that the location of multiple smooths relative to one another is irrelevant for the estimation of each compartmentalized smooth. Extending this logic back to the problem of creating a temporal soap film model, what issues arise from simply adding a constant value to the latitudes and longitudes corresponding to a given year of data and its boundary? Instead of fitting multiple smooths across years (as the TPRS model above), the hack-y soap film model fits multiple smooths over space, where each fitted smooth represents a different year of data. The predictions would be biased in a normal TPRS model, but that doesn't seem to be the case in a soap film model.

```
m2 <- gam(density ~ s(x, y, 
                     bs = "so",
                     xt = list(bnd = bound, nmax = 500)),
          data = syn_dat, method = "REML",
          knots = grid)
```

[image]

Am I crazy? Is there a simpler, less hack-y way to do this? Unfortunately, my knowledge of soap films is limited to Gavin Simpson's (fantastic) [tutorial](https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2016/03/27/soap-film-smoothers/).

Not surprisingly, the soap film model has a lower predictive error and is a better fit overall: [image]

Comment: Interesting problem! Can I ask why the species extent from year to year should act as a boundary that we shouldn't smooth across? This doesn't compute to me and if we could avoid this constraint it would simplify matters considerably.

Comment: I'm glad you think so! The boundary was created based on aerial imagery of the plant distribution, so there is no density outside of the boundary (well, there's some but it is negligible). The plant grows clonally and density naturally decreases towards the boundary, so the soap film model also captures the biology of the species nicely.